# Remove views in single post

Tags: statistics

How to remove views in a single post like in this picture: [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's likely going to be in your themes single.php file. Perhaps check for a function call to get the number of views, and comment out the code.

Comment: is this teh code :
 $posticon = mom_option('post_icon');

                                    while ( have_posts() ) :
         the_post();
     setPostViews(get_the_ID());